# Is this too much rust to repair?

Tags: mitsubishi, rust, lancer, underbody

I (maybe foolishly), recently purchased this car privately. I failed to inspect the underbody of the vehicle accurately. It's a 2011 Mitsubishi Lancer. I was wondering is this rust too much to get repaired? If so, how much would it set me back?

[image: picture of exciting rust number 1]

[image: exciting rust number 2]

[image: exciting rust number 3]

[image: exciting rust number 4]

--
Here are the images!

https://ibb.co/svkJD5Z
https://ibb.co/FmQjbKL
https://ibb.co/wrrPmnQ
https://ibb.co/s2c2BbX
https://ibb.co/Tt19fkh

Comment: There is rust converter spray cans you can buy, hose it down with that, it will covert the rust to black oxide, then undercoat over top of it once it dries.

Answer (score 1):

If that is the worst rust on the vehicle, then I would say you have bought a solid car and there is nothing to worry about as far as rust is concerned at the moment.

A wire brush down and a coat of under seal should keep that rust at bay.

Comment: It looks very superficial. "Too much to repair" is when you look at down your feet and you can see the road through a hole in the floor pan :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is this too much rust to repair?

No, i do not think so.

The rust on the solid steel of the frame has not reached the cancerous stage, It is mostly surface rust and can be remedied.

The rust on the sheet metal is a little deeper but it does not look like it is terrible or causing structural problems.

There is no way for us to give you any idea on costs.

Do your research on dealing with rust and once you have dealt with it you may consider an undercoating to extend the life of your car. (*There are pros and cons to undercoating, if the roads in your area are salted for snow and ice it may be beneficial*.)